# How can I retract an accepted answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

If I accept an answer in **my** question, how can I retract my proposal (and accept another)?

Furthermore, will I lose any reputation retracting answer acception? Will the answerer lose any reputation with his answer being retracted?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the Accept checkmark of the other question? That should do it.

Comment: Or just clicking the checkmark again will unaccept without accepting another.

Comment: Note: unaccepting an answer removes the 15 rep from the OP. The SE users tend to emotionally overestimate such little rep losses, and they will know, who did it (accept votes are inherently not anonym). But if it is the right way, this is what you have to do. If you think the poster has many good posts, you can check some of them, maybe some of them contains enough useful information which deserves an upvote (don't do this as compensation, vote up only really good posts!).

Comment: Supporting (mostly) what @peterh said, but adding a word of caution: Be careful. Do not let that be a driving force for you. If you unaccept an answer (which you have every right to do) and receive some backlash from the occasional disgruntled user, do not engage (unless you have some constructive input on their answer, of course). The quality of these sites relies on voting patterns based on content and usefulness, not based on attempting to appease an overly sensitive user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do the same procedure you have done to accept answer.

Click on the Green Tick Mark again and the answer become unaccepted.

If you just want to accept another answer,

You can simply accept the answer by clicking the tick mark.

Then the old-accepted answer become unaccepted and the new one become accepted.

**is there any reputation change in unaccepting an answer?**

Yes there is.

When you accept an answer, you will get +2 ( a total of 2 reputation per question. won't get for changing accepted answers.)

When you unaccept answer, you will loss the 2 reputation.

Answer (score 5):

Just click the checkmark again to unaccept. Or click it on somebody else's answer to move it.

As per the tooltip on the accept button (you'll see it if you hover over it with your mouse):

> Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution (click again to undo)

Or (if you've already clicked it):

> Click to undo acceptance of this answer

Comment: Sorry but I never see any tooltips. Isn't there tooltips on mobile SE sites?