# More precision of stat "member for x days" on touchscreen devices

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

[image]

I would like to see more precise stat like "member for y days" than current "member from x months" (or it could expand if clicked to show day counts)

"Mouseover" doesn't work for touchscreen devices.

Comment: @Stijn you mean first notification when account is created? Sorry iam lazy to go through that back.

Comment: No. In your screenshot where you have drawn a box. Hover over the "6 months" and a tooltip will appear with the exact date of registration.

Comment: @animuson iam not on pc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's not spend an awful lot of developer time on implementing that feature as it has so little added value. Instead use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/648810?UserId=340369) on SEDE.

```sql
select datediff(yy, creationdate, getdate()) years
     , datediff(q, creationdate, getdate()) quarters
     , datediff(m, creationdate, getdate()) months
     , datediff(ww, creationdate, getdate()) weeks
     , datediff(d, creationdate, getdate()) days
     , datediff(hh, creationdate, getdate()) hours
     , datediff(mi, creationdate, getdate()) minutes
     , datediff(s, creationdate, getdate()) seconds
from users 
where id = ##userid?340369##
```

When run today this is your result for MSE

[image]

Do note that on the full site you can see your exact joining date of an site if you hover with your mouse over the time:

[image: hover]

On a Windows Surface I need to touch the 6 months for a couple of seconds to see the tooltip appear. I expect other devices that support touch events would show similar behavior.

This feature exists for most of the human readable times.

Comment: (+1)I liked your effort. But someday tomorrow,another person will come and ask for same feature request. It would b more better to add some time and improve mobile site features..

Comment: Is there a way to pop up the tool tips on mobile devices (e.g. the tablet in the OP's screenshot)? Confusion about tool tips on mobile devices came up in an indirect manner at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292907/how-can-i-retract-an-accepted-answer#comment951635_292908 as well.

Comment: @JasonC there is pop-up when long pressed on user profile. [Just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBI6H.png)

Comment: @Fawad What happens if you long press the "6 months" in your screenshot?

Comment: When you press it in the screenshot, nothing will happen @JasonC